# Read user fingerprint and assign to user - zk

Tags: php, time-and-attendance, zkteco

I am using php zklib to manage zk time attendance machine.

I am able to connect to device.

What I need is I want to add a new user to the machine from system, I can add the user information using `CMD_USER_WRQ`. Now I need to invoke the device, so that the user can place his finger and the device should register his finger to the user.